# NoClassDefFoundError exception in Spring Boot Starter application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to add security to the Spring Boot Starter Project. Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xxxx.course-api</groupId>
<artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>course-api</name>
<description>Course-API Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

When I ran my code it is not generating me a default password as it should do. When I try to add a custom security config class and run the project it throws me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception. Below is the error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                                             o     org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1189)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:862)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:848)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:834)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:788)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
at com.xxxxx.course.api.CourseApiApplication.main(CourseApiApplication.java:14)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 24 more
```

Below is my security config class:

```
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
      import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
     import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
     import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
      import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

     @EnableWebSecurity
     public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String USER = "USER";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/Courses/{id}").hasRole(USER).and().formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder manager) throws Exception {
        manager.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("xxxxx").password("password").roles(USER).and().withUser("yyyyyy")
                .password("password").roles(USER, ADMIN);
    }

}
```

What exactly is the mistake ?

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` before doing a rebuild. This will remove dependencies from your local repository and will download fresh jars. Might be that a jar is corrupted.

Comment: @M.Deinum doing _mvn dependency:purge-local-repository_ worked. Yes the jar was corrupted.